# chrome debugger ignore list pattern to ignore library

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-devtools

I have vue project and I'd like to go only through the steps of my script using the debugger. Ignore all node_modules scripts and the vue framework call stack.

I guess it's possible to use the ignore list in the setting of chrome dev tools and add a pattern.

I tried `/vue\.js$` with it keeps step in vue code

[image]